# SQL Server getting unique records

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, locking

I'm starting a project where I need to ensure that a large volume of users can obtain a promotional code for multiple promotions.

The codes have a monetary value attached to them so it is vital that only one code goes out to each user and no two users can ever receive the code.

My plan so far is to create a table in SQL Server known as `code_pool` and do a bulk insert of codes each time.

SQL Server 2005 table would look like this...

```
[id](int pk), [promo_code] varchar(150), [promotion_id](int fk)
```

Users would then retreive each code using a stored proc that would get the first record from the table for that promotion and then delete (or update) the record before returning the code as the result of the procedure.

My question is how do I ensure that the record is properly locked so that only one user may ever obtain each record and that no two users accessing the proc concurrently will ever receive the same code?

Do I need to lock the table/records and if so how would this stack up in a busy production environment?

Answer (score 2):

One very handy built in data type for generating unique codes that are not easily guessible is the `uniqueidentifier` data type. You can use this to generate a unique code by making it have an auto-generated value (using the newid() function). Because GUIDs are in HEX and not generated sequentially unlike identity columns, it isn't possible to predict what codes have or will be generated which will make your process less vulnerable to someone just trying codes in sequence. The number of possible uniqueidentifiers is very large.

I've made the assumption that you will only want one promo code per person for each of your promos. The way you can do this in your database is by having a table, my example calls it PromoTest, which has a primary key on both of these columns which will ensure they remain unique. I didn't add a concept of 'Used' to indicate if the person has used the code but that's quite trivial to do.

To create your table with the primary key constraint and the auto-generated value run the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PromoTest](
[personid] [bigint] NOT NULL,   [promocategory] [int] NOT NULL, 
[promocode] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,  
   CONSTRAINT [PK_PromoTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (   
         [personid] ASC,    
         [promocategory] ASC )
      WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS 
= ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PromoTest] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PromoTest_promocode]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [promocode]
```

To then have a stored procedure that inserts a new promo code or selects the existing one is quite trivial, and due to the primary key constraint you cannot physically insert two codes of the same type for the same person.

The stored procedure can be defined as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOrCreatePromoCode 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @PersonId bigint,
    @PromoCategory int, 
    @PromoCode uniqueidentifier OUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT PromoCode FROM PromoTest WHERE personid = @PersonId AND promocategory = @PromoCategory))
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PromoTest (personid, promocategory) VALUES (@PersonId, @PromoCategory)      
      END
    SET @PromoCode = (SELECT PromoCode FROM PromoTest WHERE personid = @PersonId AND promocategory = @PromoCategory)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

don't you want to add a column e.g. in_use (int)? when you generate new promocode, in_use=0, when your stored proc obtains non-used promo code it selects first code where in_use = 0, and then updates it to 1

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something similar, but like this:

```
Table UsedCodes
[id] int identity PK,
[userId] whatever,
[PromoId] int FK

Table Promotions
[PromoId] int pk,
[PromoCode] nvarchar
```

When a user gets a promo code, you would insert a value into used codes, and the promotion code delivered to them would be a concatenation of the promo code and the ID in the used codes table.

You could then also enforce a unique constraint on UserId | PromoId on the used codes table, to ensure only a single code per promo per user.

This has the advantage of retaining a record of the codes used, and reduces the complexity of needing your bulk insert, which could potentially introduce dups by accident.  It also has the advantage of requiring no locking...

Answer (score 0):

[John P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223799/sql-server-getting-unique-records/4224341#4224341) has given you an excellent answer but I find GUIDs are unwieldy for use as a voucher code due to the string length.

Have a look at the question [how to generate a voucher code in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4713584/243925) and of course my answer :) Although you are asking for a SQL solution you can probably adapt the ideas given there.

I would also recommend you do not delete the codes which have been used; how will you be sure the code presented by the customer was created by your system?